# CSS rotation slow

Tags: animation, css, rotation, flip

http://jsfiddle.net/egEq2/

```
.badge {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    position: relative;
}   
.back, .front {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
}
.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    overflow: hidden;
}   
.front {
}
.product-action {
    display: inline-block;
}   
.product-action:hover .back {   
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.product-action:hover .front {      
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}​
```

... works, but flips too slow, can I change the speed?

Also, can I add width somehow so the flip looks like a board and not a thin paper? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You specified the speed already:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in;
                                      ^^
```

Change it to something like `0.3s`: http://jsfiddle.net/egEq2/1/

Comment: Ah great, got it. Also, is there any way to make it look 3d while flipping?

Comment: You could give the card a background color or border. Without that, it won't look like it's rotating: http://jsfiddle.net/egEq2/2/